# How do I keep sidekiq always up on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

Whenever I run `heroku run bundle exec sidekiq`, I see all my background jobs being done, however, I want them to be able to go without me needing to be there. When I exit out of that terminal tab, sidekiq stops working. How would I mitigate that?

Also, I've read something about procfiles and increasing workers. I don't know what procfiles are and I don't know how to increase workers either.

Basically, I'm a newbie trying to get sidekiq set up to run on Heroku for my Rails app. I want it to be running at all times.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file named ./Procfile with the following in it:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

- [sidekiq on Heroku](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#heroku)
- more on [Procfiles](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)
- [foreman gem](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman)